# YoloV5 Calibration

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I'm currently tackling the task of calibrating object detection models specifically tailored for medical imaging applications. Despite extensive online research, I've encountered difficulties in finding comprehensive information and resources that cater to the unique demands of this domain. While I have identified several relevant papers, a significant number of them lack the crucial details needed to reproduce their reported results.

To provide some context, I am working on a project aimed at enhancing the accuracy and reliability of detecting anomalies in medical images. This necessitates a well-calibrated model to ensure precise predictions. If anyone has experience or expertise in calibrating detection models, particularly within the context of medical imaging, your insights and recommendations for more comprehensive resources would be greatly appreciated.